# Is the sentence in bold a subjunctive mood and how to understand it?

Tags: sentence-construction

> ***In fairness, though, investors couldn't have found adequate shelter in the yuan even had they wanted to.*** Despite all the hype about the
>   yuan's growing stature, the universe of yuan assets in which global
>   funds can invest is minuscule. And size matters when it comes to
>   measuring the importance of international currencies.

Can the sentence in bold be parsed in the following:

> In fairness, though, investors couldn't have found adequate shelter in
>   the yuan even had they wanted to.
>   = In fairness, though, investors
>   couldn't have found adequate shelter in the yuan even if they had
>   wanted to.

But I don't know the meaning of it. 
This article is from: [enter link description here](http://cn.wsj.com/gb/20140409/and071931_ENversion.shtml)

Comment: Yes, *had* is the past subjunctive as used in a hypothetical (= not real) conditional clause. We normally use *if* + past subjunctive for hypothetical conditional clauses, but in certain circumstances we can leave out *if*. The main clause, with *couldn't*, could also be said to be in the past subjunctive; however, because only a fixed number of (modal) verbs are normally used in the main clause to an hypothetical condition, we usually just say "it is *could*" rather than "it is the past subjunctive of *can*", even though this is probably the origin of *could/would/should/might* there.

Comment: @Cerberus Don't you want to turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You're spot on. Let me give another example so my answer looks better to get me more votes:

> Had I been there on time, I'd be dead. (Gotta love depressing examples.)

This is identical in meaning to:

> If I had been there on time, I'd be dead.

It's a strange pattern of words and letters and difficult to deduce a meaning from. In general, I wouldn't recommend dropping the 'if' as it normally makes a sentence much clearer.

One more example:

> Were I rich man, I'd yubby dibby dibby dibby dibby dibby dibby dum.
>
> If I were a rich man, yubby dibby dibby dibby dibby dibby dibby dum.